# Java can't access txt file in src/main/resources

Tags: java

I'm trying to get my txt file with `getClass.getResourcesAsStream()`, but it is not working. The code is below.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        File file = new File(getClass().getResourceAsStream("example.txt"));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        fis.read(byteArray);
        String data = new String(byteArray);
        String[] stringArray = data.split("\r\n");
        System.out.println(stringArray.length+" lines");
    }
```

I am getting an exception that says no suitable constructor found for File(InputStream)

I don't know how to fix this and make it functional.

Comment: That is because File is not for resources on the class path. (Path also covers resources).

Comment: Then what should I change it to?

Comment: Try using a String as the constructor's parameter.

Comment: What does ``getClass().getResourceAsStream("example.txt")`` do?

Comment: It was a way to import the resources of a java project (like txt files and more) that I found but I am still having some trouble figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
URL url = getClass(U).getResource("example.txt");
Path path = Paths.get(url.toURI()):
byte[] byteArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);
String data = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I explicitly added the Charset, as otherwise it varies per installation of your software, and a resource has a known charset/encoding.

The path is relative to the package path of `getClass()` if not preceded by "/". It might be better to use `Xyz.class` instead - in case of a child class. Or use an absolute path "/example.txt".

Comment: This won't work if you package your project as a WAR or JAR. You need to use `getResourceAsStream` then read the stream.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. a Path `"jar:file: ... .jar! ... /example.txt"` should work too.